# ATR smart card, change ATR, addition

Tags: smartcard

Is there any way to change the ATR on a smart card? cards nxp jcop j2a40

ATR need to change or add to it to work properly with the hardware card

Answer (score 5):

In the cards I know, ATR is set during pre-personalization: both communication parameters and identification details such as the Historical Bytes. The commands to do so are totally vendor-specific (for example, NXP JCOP has its special commands to set ATR). The specification is usually available from the vendor.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer given by @mictter, some javacards allow changing the historical bytes in the ATR using [`GPSystem.setATRHistBytes()`](http://www.win.tue.nl/pinpasjc/docs/apis/gp211/org/globalplatform/GPSystem.html#setATRHistBytes(byte[],%20short,%20byte)).

It depends on your desired change whether it suffices or not as it can't change other bytes of the ATR (expect the lower nibble of the `T0` which encodes the number of the historical bytes present).

As far as I know at least some JCOPs do support this.

Beware that the applet MUST have the `Card Reset`/`Default Selected` privilege to be allowed to use this method.

Good luck!